# Dense $G_{\delta}$ set implies comeagre set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space. Show that if $D$ is a dense $G_{\delta}$ set, then $D$ is comeagre, that is, countable intersection of dense sets.

My attempt: Let $D=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{D_n}$ where $D_n$ is open. Since $D$ is dense in $X$, then we have $X = \overline{D}=\overline{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{D_n}}=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{\overline{D_n}}$. Hence, **$\overline{D_n} =X$** for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $X \backslash D_n$ is nowhere dense. Since $X \backslash D$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, $D$ is comeagre.

Question: Is $\overline{D_n} = X$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I think your definitions are mixed up.  "Comeagre" is not the same as "countable intersection of dense sets".  A countable intersection of dense sets can be empty, even in a complete metric space.

Comment: I suppose comegre is the complement of meager set, which is countable union of nowhere dense sets.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct definition.  But a countable intersection of dense sets need not be comeagre.  (The complement of a dense set does not have to be nowhere dense.)

Comment: And this is actually the flaw in your argument.  $\overline{D_n} = X$ does not imply that $X \setminus D_n$ is nowhere dense, for arbitrary sets $D_n$.  You have to also use the fact that $D_n$ is open.

Comment: But for your actual question: note that $\overline{D} = X$ and $D \subset D_n$.

Comment: Oh and also: the "identity" $\overline{\bigcap_n D_n} = \bigcap_n \overline{D_n}$ is false in general.

Comment: then the statement in the title is false?

Comment: The statement in the title is true, but you have not given a correct proof of it.

Comment: @nate-eldredge What about making an answer out of your comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, the closure of $D_n$ is $X$.  This is almost immediate: since $D$ is the intersection of the sets $D_n$, we must have $D \subseteq D_n$ for every $n$.  It is a standard fact that for every pair of sets $A,B$, if $A \subseteq B$ then $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$.  (Note that $\overline{B}$ is a closed set that contains $A$.)  So we must have $X = \overline{D} \subseteq \overline{D_n}$.  The reverse inclusion is obvious, since $\overline{D_n}$ is by definition a subset of $X$.

But there are two other gaps in your proof.

> $\overline{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{D_n}}=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{\overline{D_n}}$

This is not true, in general.  (For a counterexample, consider the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$.  Enumerate the rationals as $q_n$ and let $D_n = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{q_n\}$.  Then the sets $D_n$ are dense (and even open), so $\overline{D_n} = \mathbb{Q}$ and the right side equals $\mathbb{Q}$.  But $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} D_n = \emptyset$ so the left side is empty.)

> Hence, **$\overline{D_n} =X$** for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $X \backslash D_n$ is nowhere dense.

It is not true for general sets $A$ that if $\overline{A} = X$ (i.e. if $A$ is dense) then $X \setminus A$ is nowhere dense.  (For a counterexample, take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $A = \mathbb{Q}$.  Double check that you are using the correct definition of "nowhere dense".)   It does happen to be true for *open* sets, but you need to argue this more carefully.

Once you show this fact (if $A$ is open and dense then $X \setminus A$ is nowhere dense) then the proof is pretty easy.  The sets $D_n$ are open, and above we argued that they are dense, so therefore $X \setminus D_n$ is nowhere dense for each $n$.  By De Morgan's law we have $X \setminus D = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (X \setminus D_n)$ so we see that $X \setminus D$ is meager, meaning that $D$ is comeager.